# how to put all files from folder and subfolders into an array

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am using this function to grab all the files from folders and it's subfolder. this works fine. But i need an array of all these files.

```
 function get_all_directory_and_files($dir){
 
     $dh = new DirectoryIterator($dir);   
     // Dirctary object 
     foreach ($dh as $item) {
         if (!$item->isDot()) {
            if ($item->isDir()) {
                get_all_directory_and_files("$dir/$item");
            } else {
                echo $dir . "/" . $item->getFilename();
                echo "<br>";
            }
         }
      }
   }
 
  # Call function 
  
  get_all_directory_and_files("data/comments");
```

so how can i put all the files into an array like this:

```
$all_files[] = // contains all the files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

function get_all_directory_and_files($dir) {
    $results = [];
    $dh = new DirectoryIterator($dir);   
    // Dirctary object 
    foreach ($dh as $item) {
        if (!$item->isDot()) {
            if ($item->isDir()) {
                $results = array_merge($results, get_all_directory_and_files($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item));
            } else {
                $results[] = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $item->getFilename();
            }
        }
    }

    return $results;
}

var_dump( get_all_directory_and_files("/tmp") );
```